# empty screen shot of a div including canvas using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, webgl, html2canvas, panoramas

I am using html to canvas library to make a screen shot of a div which includes a canvas as the first children node and it returns a white space. The div is holding a panorama image using Panolens library.

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#hey")).then(canvas => {...})
```

Then I tried to set preserveDrawingBuffer of the canvas to true and I still get the same result.

```
 const gl = document.querySelector("#hey").children[0].getContext('webgl2', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
                    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#hey")).then(canvas => {..})
```

Does anyone have experience?

Comment: I got the same problem.

Comment: @HimanshuRawat please share here if you find a trick for that  :)